# Remove select placeholder after selecting option

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, wordpress

After selecting option from list hide placeholder (Select option). If after clicked on select box placeholder must be hidden.

```html
<select class="name">
    <option value="">Select Option</option>
    <option value="1">Option 1</option>
    <option value="2">Option 2</option>
    <option value="3">Option 3</option>
    <option value="4">Option 4</option>
    <option value="5">Option 5</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could do it like this:

```js
$("select").change(function() {
 $(this).find("option:first").hide();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select class="name">
  <option value="">Select Option</option>
  <option value="1">Option 1</option>
  <option value="2">Option 2</option>
  <option value="3">Option 3</option>
  <option value="4">Option 4</option>
  <option value="5">Option 5</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can set a js-handler, to remove the Option-noe (here the jQuery Version):

```
<select class="name" id="myselect">
<option value="">Select Option</option>
<option value="1">Option 1</option>
<option value="2">Option 2</option>
<option value="3">Option 3</option>
<option value="4">Option 4</option>
<option value="5">Option 5</option>
</select>
```

and the js

```
jQuery(function(){
    jQuery ('#myselect').on('change', function(){
    jQuery(this).find('[value=""]').remove();
  })
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/k08zj6r9/

if you wish, you can disable the node, instead of remove.

```
jQuery(this).find('[value=""]').attr('disabled','disabled');
```